# Форма для ManyToMany с доп. полями

Tags: symfony, symfony4

**Дано**

Сущность 1 (здания): Building [id, name]

Сущность 2 (справочник опций): Options [id, name]

Сущность 3 (опции у зданий): BuildingOptions [building_id, options_is, is_paid_option]

Если бы не дополнительное поле is_paid_option, то связь была бы ManyToMany и всё было бы по документации. Но BuildingOptions  имеет собственное поле is_paid_option. Это превращает её в отдельную сущность, с двумя полями ManyToOne и одним boolean.

**Требуется**

Создать форму создания Building, в которой показан список возможных опций доступных в Options, но каждая позиция должна содержать два чекбокса: enabled и isPaid.

EntityType позволяет создать список, но не позволяет добавить второй чекбокс. Так же в попытке использовать CollectionType был создан отдельный Type:

```
class BuildingOptionsFormType extends AbstractType
{
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('isPaid', CheckboxType::class)
        ->add('buildingOptions', EntityType::class, [
            'required' => false
        ])
        ->add('building', EntityType::class, [
            'required' => true
        ])
    ;
}
}
```

но не понятно как список доступных опций вывести в виде нескольких десятков этих Type-ов. В дальнейшем нужно участь что эта же форма будет использоваться для редактирования, то есть нужно будет подавать начальные данные с отмеченными опциями для этой формы из уже готового Building.

Подскажите пожалуйста как создать такую форму. Спасибо.

Comment: На самом деле не очень понятно, однако если я понял то что понял, у вас все опции должны быть описаны отдельной моделью, где есть имя опции и  требуемые данные, а именно isPaid и Enabled. Сделали форму 1 (и, возможно, отрисовку в твиге при надобности). Так же есть другая модель, в которой есть поле options и там живут опции (одна ко многим, например) и уже создаете форму 2 для данной модели, где поле опции будет описываться как коллекция той формы, которую вы предварительно создали. (не забываем про multiple true если нужно). Можно попробовать так, если что то понятно о чем я

Comment: @zalex да, я понял. А где я заполняю коллекцию? В контроллере получается?

Comment: Пока писал, понял что вы спросили (сразу не въехал). 
Ну тут тоже есть варианты.Если вы хотите создавать эти опции динамически (а видимо это вариант неплохой), то читаете документацию по этому поводу https://symfony.com/doc/4.4/form/form_collections.html
тут нужно будет еще на фронте немного поработать. Вы при заполнении форм именно на фронте добавляет/удаляете новые опции, которые хотели бы.Имена опций вы  можете сделать как массив для choice непосредственно в форме(или передать даже их туда через options и отрисовать) или для перечисления этих самых options вам нужна будет еще одна модель.

Comment: И в этой (или может правильней назвать это сущность) модели вы перечисляете список доступных options, тогда чуть усложняется ваша таблицы и взаимодействие друг с другом (плюс написать еще CRUD для заполнения сущности), но в таком случае вы можете, например, описать что какие то опции присущи тем или иным сущностям... ну в общем о чем это я... (только что увидел что вы обновили вопрос, стало более понятно)

Answer (score 0):

При реализации связи ManyToMany, нельзя создать форму с доп.полями. Вам нужна реализовать связь через промежуточную таблицу. Пример можно посмотреть [тут](https://symfonycasts.com/screencast/collections/many-to-many-extra-fields).
После того как вы поменяет отношениях в сущностях, вы можете свободно использовать тип формы Collection для отображения всех дополнительных полей в форме.